# Problem with HashRouter in React can't fix it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, router

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dV15Z.png)

using HashRouter it shows like

http://localhost:3000/simple-blog#/simple-blog/verify 
this but i don't want it to be repeated

I wrote this way...

```
`ReactDOM.render(
    <HashRouter>
        <App />
    </HashRouter>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);`
```

is it real to have something like 
http://localhost:3000/#/simple-blog/verify
or
http://localhost:3000/simple-blog/verify